# Detect Touches on Edges of Apple TV Remote

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, tvos, apple-tv

When using the Apple TV remote to interact with a tvOS application, the location of the initial touch event is always the same (e.g., x: 960.0, y: 540.0) because there is no relation to the view the user is interacting with.

Apple's video player shows the option to skip forward/backward 10 seconds if the user touches the edges of the Apple TV remote. **How does Apple detect the user touches the edge of the Apple TV remote?** This is possible if the user is swiping the touch area of the Apple TV remote, but Apple's video player also does this when the user puts their finger on the edge of the touch area of the Apple TV remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a solution: https://dcordero.me/posts/directional_clicks_on_tvos.html

He uses the GameController API to treat the touchpad like a d-pad.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Adam.

Comment: This GameController solution isn’t working for me on the latest tvOS. Is it working for you @BartJacobs?

Comment: It is working for me on tvOS 14.3. Which version are you testing with?

Comment: Oh it looks like it does work on device, it’s only the simulator that no longer works. Thanks Bart!